# how to add authentication to a wsgiref python web service

Tags: python, basic-authentication, wsgiref

I am working on a sample code given in the python documentation, the code is:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server, demo_app

httpd = make_server('', 8000, demo_app)
print "Serving HTTP on port 8000..."

# Respond to requests until process is killed
httpd.serve_forever()

# Alternative: serve one request, then exit
httpd.handle_request()
```

I can access this through the localhost on port 8000, but now if I want to pass username/password with the "localhost:8000 username, password" how do I do this. I have figured out how I would get to know if the authentication was unsuccessful but not how to actually receive the username/password for checking..

Any hints, and tips.....

Cheers,

Comment: Its better to generate API keys for users and they use that as a key=xxx argument to the query string... you then verify that its a valid key and serve the content...

Comment: @Joran, thanks for the tip but I don't have options here. Any work arounds you might know about?

Comment: just have them add user=xxx&pass=xxx and validate them before you serve it...but this is not very safe as most users will be sending their credentials over unsecured connections

Comment: yup but how to do this, do you have any sample code...

Comment: I dont know how to with wsgiref ... but in django it would be something like http://ideone.com/0smDW in django for example...

Comment: According to the Python documentation for wsgiref: "Each web application is callable with two arguments, environment dictionary and a start_response function".  So its different from django, I think... Anyways thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass username/password in the query string like `http://localhost:8000?username=x&password=y`, you can retrieve them in your WSGI handler function from the environ dict: `environ['QUERY_STRING']`. You can use `urlparse.parse_qs` from the standard library to parse it. If this is code that's going into production, I second Joran, you should use at least HTTP Basic Authentication and some authentication middleware like [barrel](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/barrel).

Comment: thanks a lot, and yes I would definitely look into barrel. But for the time being this would work for the demo. Thanks again